# How to sort recyclerview by boolean value

Tags: android, collections, android-recyclerview

I have `Recyclerview` that contains data which is university material. I want to sort it by `boolean silabus`.

I want if `silabus == true`, Its always showing the data in the top of recycler view, I do this logic but it still not working at all. Please help

```
 Collections.sort(listMateri, new Comparator<MateriKuliah>() {
                                public int compare(MateriKuliah o1, MateriKuliah o2) {
                                    if (o1.isSilabus() || o2.isSilabus()) {
                                        return -1;

                                    } else {

                                        return 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Uh sorry, I've been searching before. But I dont got it. Thanks for your attention sagar

Answer (score 0):

> try this before passing your list to the adapter

**(after API call and before adapter notifydatasetchanged)**

```
Collections.sort(yourLists, new Comparator<YourList>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(YourList lhs, YourList rhs) {
            return lhs.getId().compareTo(rhs.getId());
        }
    });
```